# mingw and codeblocks for c and c++ which works on windows 7 64bit?

Tags: c, windows-7, mingw, codeblocks, mingw-w64

I have a windows 7 64 bit (home premium).

the problem is i am trying to learn C and when i complete in then go on to learn c++. The problem is i coudnt find a working compiler and IDE. I finally got on to code blocks and mingw 64 bit .I can indivisually install them but cant find a tutorial or any instructions to set codeblocks to use mingw-64 as the compiler.

I am open to options for other compiler and ide to use. I am trying to avoid visual basic as i have heard that its very confusing and difficult for beginners and should be avoided.

Note: I have already tried the combined codeblocks and mingw binary but it doesnt work on 64 bit as mingw packed is for 32 bit(only reason i could think of).

Answer (score 1):

The 32-bit package should work fine on your machine, and for the purposes of learning the languages.

Answer (score 0):

The native C++ compiler for Windows is from Microsoft. You can get the free Express edition from their site.

[Visual C++ 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express)

Comment: can you also c programs on it and isnt it too confusing for starters as i have heard??

Comment: Default is to compile .c files as C, and .cpp as C++. It is C89 though, an not C99 (or C11). It *does* come as a complete package with a standard Windows install program and no configuration required.